# jquery ajax event not working in ie

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery

I had a ajax called like this

```
 $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: "{}",
    url: "/Clases/WebMethods.asmx/crearMenu",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: createMenu
});
```

This works perfect in Firefox and Chrome, but it doesn't in IE, the most rare part is that when turn on the developers tools in the browser, it works!!!. Can someone help me, if it's a configuration in the browser or something else. I already tried erasing the cache and cookies of the browsers and doesn't solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: `data: "{}",` should probably be `data: {}` - you're sending a string which contains a couple of braces, not an empty object. Do you see the ajax hit show up on the server?

Comment: Is it the ajax request or the createMenu function? I have had it in the past where special effects in jQuery bog down IE too much, so it just gives up. It could be that something in the callback is the problem, not the request itself.

Comment: yeap the called get's to the server, let me try your solution

Comment: btw id you are not sending in data.. dnt set it at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come across this frequently in IE and generally, if something works with the developer tools enabled and not without, you will have a console.log somewhere in your code that is erroring as there is no console, preventing the rest of the code from executing.

Comment: jajaja you're right i have in my code a console.log jajaja i didn't know that thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the success function not working on IE (See my thread: [JQuery button click not working after ajax form submit on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820163/jquery-button-click-not-working-after-ajax-form-submit-on-ie)). I solved it by making success callback a native JS method and not to user JQuery.

See if that solves your problem.